# Relations vs data constraints in database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

To simplify the description let's assume we've got a DB model with TimeScopes (ID, start, end) and Processes with FK (TimeScopes.ID), and this is one-to-many relation where all processes holding a reference to the TimeScopes.ID are running within the given time scope.

So first, you define a single time scope and pick multiple processes running at that time scope.

```
TimeScopes
  |__
     Processes
```

There are some additional constraints in the application (no DB triggers in the DB so far), like assumptions that TimeScopes are not overlapping - only one TimeScope could be active at the time.

Now I've got a new requirement to add some new Processes that could be initiated at any moment in time without any constraint - so effectively they do not have to, but they could be running simultaneously at the same time (in parallel).

In this case, someone would define the process first and then assign it to such a new, single Process multiple time scopes without a constraint mentioned earlier. So this would be quite the opposite relation one Process to many TimeScopes.

```
Processes
  |__
     TimeScopes
```

I'm looking for help and advice on how to solve it?

From the relations perspective, I can adjust the relation between TimeScopes and Processes to many-to-many by adding a table to define relations in both directions.

```
TimeScopes
  |__
   __ TP-Relations
  |
Processes
```

What makes me uncertain about that is the additional time constraint from the existing model. That drives me to think about an alternative solution and define maybe a separate tables for NewProcesses and NewTimeScopes

```
NewProcesses
  |__
     NewTimeScopes
```

and later combine results between two models in queries by use of UNION statement.

Which seems to be better? Any other or better ideas?

**Update/Rephrase the question**

Let's say we've got Entities "A" and "B" in many-to-many relation made with additional "AB" (junction) table.

For some records representing A->B in 1-to-many relation, there are some additional constraints about the A records. Let's say we've got some triggers to watch each record in A doesn't cross the boundaries of another A record.

For other records representing B->A in 1-to-many relation these boundaries are not always acceptable so shouldn't be forced/checked.

Question: How to deal with such a problem?

- Modify the model/relations, how?
- Modify the triggers? but is it even possible on the DB level to recognise that some records would be entered for A->B vs B->A relations?

Comment: I'm reading your information, and I can't determine the relationship between a process and a time scope.  Every job scheduling system I've ever worked with dealt only with processes.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm not sure how you can tell about scheduling anything without reference to time scope? How about Cronjobs? You define the time scope (not in terms of start and end but how often) and which script to execute, right? Cron doesn't check if there is any other job running at the same time, so this is possible illustration for my NewProcess requirement even I used that in more general/abstract context.

Comment: Process one triggers process two.  Process three must wait for process one to complete before starting.  Process four is independent and can start at any time.  Where's the time reference?  The only time reference I'm familiar with is the batch job window starts a 6 pm, when everyone goes home for the day.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc What you've wrote makes sense but has got nothing to do with my case and the question. FYI here are different meaning of word process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process. As I've mentioned earlier I used that as general abstract concept. Your feedback doesn't bring anything useful, quite opposite.

Comment: Can you list the tables that are "Entities"?  Then note that 1:many "relationships" need an id in one table to link to the other.  Many:many relationships need a junction table between them.

Comment: @RickJames Entities are TimeScopes and Processes (in the abstract sense - you can think about tasks, activities, some other general actions). I am aware of the need for ids from one table referring to another - I've mentioned TimeScopes.ID as a Foreign Key (FK). The same goes for the junction table for many-to-many relation - in my case I proposed TP-Relations to play that role. Maybe I will try to update and rephrase the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is the following true?
- A timescope can have many processes
- A process can belong to many timescopes
- A timescope should not have an overlapping start or end with another timescope

Comment: @NevilleKuyt What you wrote is true except that the last sentence is true only for the cases where one timescope has got many processes.

Comment: Alas, there is no easy way to constrain "not have an overlapping start or end".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, it appears the following is true:

- A timescope can have many processes
- A process can belong to many timescopes
- A timescope should not have an overlapping start or end with another timescope **if** the timescope has more than one process.

I would separate this out into two questions:

#### How should I model the relationship between process and timescope?

It seems that this is a straightforward many-to-many relationship, so I would include a joining table as you suggest.

#### How should I ensure the business rule about overlapping timescopes?

I don't think you can enforce this through the entity relationships in your model. You then have a few options - if you *must* implement it at the database level, a trigger on the relation table should do the job - your rule applies only if there is more than 1 process for a given timescope, which will cause an insert or update event on your join table.

I am not a huge fan of triggers - they are hard to test, hard to debug, and can lead to performance problems. If at all possible, I'd implement this in the application layer.

### Should you store different types of timescopes/processes in different tables?

This is partly philosophical, partly practical. In general, you should store similar types of entity in the same table. Especially if they vary in behaviour, but not attributes; don't repeat yourself and all that.

If you have different validation rules, but identical attributes, I'd keep them in a single table.

This is all subject to "understandability" - if your system describes mammals, keeping "humans" and "cats" in the same table with a type discriminator is probably fine. If your system describes "humans" and "tables", the fact that both have "leg_count" attributes is not a reason to keep them in the same table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was also considering an alternative solution as clearly we speak about two types of processes which differentiate by the time scope perspective. I was considering the ideas of creating another table for "other" type of processes (maybe also a separate times-scopes as well)? I'm not sure if the trigger on relation table could also check and filter starts and ends of only time-scopes belonging to one type of the processes - not all of them. I'm not planning to write triggers just wondering if and how such problem could be solved by the RDB?

Comment: P.S. I work on app which handles first type of processes already and I need to add and handle another type now. So all the triggers and check would happen in app layer but  I'm trying to figure out which way to move on would be better/cleaner etc., as it seems like it would be a huge mess one way or the other.